# Magento 1.9.3 : color swatches not working in ultimo theme

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, color-swatches

I created configurable product and enable configurable swatches from admin. And added color with "Red-swatch" in image section. Added image for simple product also.

But color swatches are not doing swap image. Please check following link:

http://superbuniforms.com/magento/special-deal/men-white-chef-coat.html

Please provide particular solution.

Thanks

Comment: working now check

Comment: Please check my screenshot. http://superbuniforms.com/magento/error.png.  Color images display in thumbnail also. And If I click on green color image not change

Comment: better, you dont create always swatch images for color, create one folder in html editor in cms as swatches. then save images as red.png, white.png like this

Comment: please explain, i could not understand.

Comment: Create one new folder as swatches under cms, save images as red.png like that for all colors 25x25

Comment: I created folder and save images as red.png. But not working yet

Comment: enable from system->configuration->configurable swatches->select color from dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59532/discussion-between-chandra-bhushan-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create one new folder under cms on the name of `Swatches`
2. Remove all images under products which are like `color-swatch`
3. Goto attributes > manage attributes > color > manage lables > save the color names in lower case letters.
4. The visibility of all associated products to the configurable products must be `not visible individually`.